# For data frames already in 'long' format, how can one make a measured variable an ID variable without transposing the whole data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am making calls to a database using a package (`brapi`) that return the necessary data in long format. The api treats certain ID variables as measured variables which is problematic because my analysis scripts need them as ID variables. I can't modify the call to the database in such a way that it will do it for me and I do not want to just `reshape2::cast` and then melt the entire thing because there are hundreds of variables which would make it expensive. Ideally, I am looking for a way to do this with `reshape2`, `plyr`, or the like.

My problem can be seen using the `mtcars` built-in data frame. Imagine you get the long data frame, `meltedcars`, with gear as an ID variable from the database but you want `cyl` as an ID variable as well. I tried obvious `dcast` commands (eg shown below) but I knew it wouldn't work because the function won't find `cyl` as a variable.

```
meltedcars<-melt(mtcars, id.vars = c("gear"))

head(meltedcars)

   gear variable value
1    4      mpg  21.0
2    4      mpg  21.0
3    4      mpg  22.8
4    3      mpg  21.4
5    3      mpg  18.7
6    3      mpg  18.1

c<-dcast(d, gear + cyl ~ variable, value.var= "value")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found
```

I have tried a number of iterations of the `dcast` function above to no avail. I have looked for similar problems for quite sometime but haven't found a fit. I know I could do this with some for loops or by melting and casting all over again, but I want to see if there is a more elegant solution. Thoughts?

**EDIT**

I should be clearer. For the purposes of this post, ID columns are the variables in long format that are used to identify the object that is being observed rather than what was being measured. Let's say we were measuring `mpg` and `disp` on all the cars in the `mtcars` data frame and we wanted **additional** identifying information about the car besides the model name in the data frame as its own column. To identify the car you have a column of car names (I have adjusted `mtcars` so that the row names are now a column within mtcars called `model`), a column of what `gear` they are, and one for how many `cyl` each car has. Then we have a variable column and value column where the kind of observation and the value of it are listed respectively. When I make the call to the database this is what I get:

head(mtcarsFromDB)

```
               model gear variable value
1         Mazda RX4    4      mpg  21.0
2     Mazda RX4 Wag    4      mpg  21.0
3        Datsun 710    4      mpg  22.8
4    Hornet 4 Drive    3      mpg  21.4
5 Hornet Sportabout    3      mpg  18.7
6           Valiant    3      mpg  18.1
```

But I want to reformat this df with `cyl`, which is currently a value of variable, as an ID column like `gear` without casting and melting the entire thing. It should look like this:

```
              model gear cyl variable value
1         Mazda RX4    4   6      mpg  21.0
2     Mazda RX4 Wag    4   6      mpg  21.0
3        Datsun 710    4   4      mpg  22.8
4    Hornet 4 Drive    3   6      mpg  21.4 
5 Hornet Sportabout    3   8      mpg  18.7
6           Valiant    3   6      mpg  18.1
```

Comment: If you check the `meltedcars`, there is no `cyl` column. `id.vars` can take multiple columns `meltedcars<-melt(mtcars, id.vars = c("gear", "cyl"))`

Comment: if you have several columns as ID identifier, maybe simply `interaction(x,y)` for your ID will work. Or use `tidyr::unite` to create a new ID column

Comment: @akrun, the problem is not the melting. I am receiving the data frame in that melted format from the database with gears as an ID column but with "cyl" in the "variable" column much like mpg above. I want to turn the "cyl" into a header (like "gear") post facto. That is after I have received it in that melted format.

Comment: For clarity, will you include the rows with variable=="cyl" in your first example data set? It still looks like there isn't any cyl in what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll replicate the problem using your approach of using `mtcars`:

```
df <- head(mtcars) # get a small chunk to work with

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = paste0("id", row_number())) # create an id variable

# use tidyr::gather() to "melt" the data:
df_long <- df %>%
  gather()
```

At this point `df_long` should be in the "problem" format that you indicated.

```
# Here's the problem area. Focus in on the last '10':
df_long %>% tail(10)

    key value
63 carb     1
64 carb     1
65 carb     2
66 carb     1
67   id   id1
68   id   id2
69   id   id3
70   id   id4
71   id   id5
72   id   id6
```

So, the `id`s are mixed in. I'm assuming that this is your issue? The following is not very elegant, but it works:

```
# get the id strings, store in `ids`
ids <- df_long %>%
  filter(key == "id") %>%
  select(value) %>%
  .[[1]]
```

Now, repeat the ids across the rows and finally, remove the original id rows in the `tail` above:

```
df_long <- df_long %>%
  mutate(newid = rep(ids, length(unique(.$key)))) %>%
  filter(key != "id") %>%
  select(newid, key, value)

head(df_long)
```

Result:

```
  newid key value
1   id1 mpg    21
2   id2 mpg    21
3   id3 mpg  22.8
4   id4 mpg  21.4
5   id5 mpg  18.7
6   id6 mpg  18.1
```

Comment: Hey @Marian Minar, that isn't quite it. Could be that I explained it wrong. I'll try to make it clearer with an edit.

Comment: I think this does what you want, though; the id is your cyl. The basic idea is separate the data frame into cyl and not-cyl, then merge the cyl values with the not-cyl data. Here Marian reps it, which I think depends on it being sorted; my preference would be a true merge.

Comment: @SamKruse my apologies, but I'm not sure how to help you, despite having read your edit. You seem to be avoiding putting the actual data that you are working with here, but if you can do that, and paste the code that you are using, we wouldn't have to talk past each other with dummy datasets. Best of luck.

Comment: Hey @MarianMinar, I think I found a way to modify your solution to fit the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating the same data set as in your edit.

```
# prepare data
cars <- mtcars
cars$model <- row.names(cars)
row.names(cars) <- seq_along(cars$mpg)

df <- melt(cars, id.vars = c("model", "gear"))
```

Now I subset df through "cyl" observations and replicate it 9 times to match melted data frame. What gives me "cyl" column with its values in the long format repeated 9 times what's consistent with the order from melted df.

```
df1 <- df[df$variable == "cyl", ]
names(df1)[4] <- "cyl" 
df1$variable <- NULL

df <- df[df$variable != "cyl", ]

# replicate data frame 9 times
df2 <- do.call("rbind", replicate(9, df1, simplify = FALSE))
```

Simply add new column to data frame from the starting point.

I think the solution is quite context-specific, so I'm not sure whether it'll work in case of your data, but maybe it'll help to think about a problem.